# Grails Security-UI Missing Menu

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have installed the `spring-security-core`, `spring-security-ui`, and  the `spring-security-acl` plugins and most of the functionality seems to work, except when I view the user controller, the base menu drop downs are blank. When I hover my mouse over the blank menu items, the dropdowns are populated correctly, but I need to be able to see the base menu items.

These are the plugins that I have installed:

```
runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.1"
    compile ':cache:1.0.0'
    compile ':mail:1.0.1'
    compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
    compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
    compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
    compile ":spring-security-acl:1.1.1"
```

I have looked at the [user guide](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/) and re-installed all of the dependencies needed by the plugin (jquery, jquery-ui, and famfamfam). I have also tried refreshed dependencies. While researching this problem I have found that most people who have had this issue have resolved it by upgrading the jquery-ui plugin, but I have the latest version.

This problem is present in IE, Firefox, and Chrome browsers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I am running Spring's Groovy/Grails version 3.2.0 tool suite